# Converting multidimensional arrays into JSON (string) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array of x and y coordinates in Javascript, where the array looks like this:

---> 0:          0                       1        ..... 
                         {x:1, y:1}, {x:1, y:2}  ..... 
      ---> 1:         0                       1        .....
                       {x:1, y:1},       {x:1, y:2}  .....

So if I for instance write Array[0][0].x, the output is 1. 
I would like to turn this array into a JSON string, which would have the following syntax:

```
 {
    "name0": [
        {
            "0": [
                {
                    "x": "1",
                    "y": "1"
                },
                {
                    "x": "1",
                    "y": "2"
                }
            ],
            "1": [
                {
                    "x": "1",
                    "y": "2"
                },
                {
                    "x": "2",
                    "y": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name1": [
        {
            "0": [
                {
                    "x": "1",
                    "y": "1"
                },
                {
                    "x": "1",
                    "y": "2"
                }
            ],
            "1": [
                {
                    "x": "1",
                    "y": "2"
                },
                {
                    "x": "2",
                    "y": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

where name0 and name1 (nameX) are not inside the mentioned 2d array, but passed from somewhere else inside the function where I am creating the `JSON`. Also, each `nameX` object is supposed to be pushed into the `JSON` with the call of this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data;
data[name1] = yourDataA;
data[name2] = yourDataB;

json = JSON.parse(data);
```

Just prepare your data var the way you need it.

Answer (score 0):

use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js library, just include the code and use the JSON.stringify() method for converting your array.